# How can PHP string indexed arrays be achieved efficiently in C++

Tags: php, c++, c, arrays, indexing

I’ve been playing around with searching text in big lists and found that using a PHP array seems to be a quick way of doing it.

E.g. if you had loads of place names and associated postcodes you could read them into a PHP array like this:

```
$place[‘place name here’] = “postcode”;
```

Then to look up you just take the place you want to look up and plug it in to the array:

```
$postcode_sought = $place[‘place I want to look up’];
```

I thought I could speed this up using C++ but of course C++ does not allow (as far as I know) arrays with a string as the index.

The only way I can think to do it is to create vectors for the place and postcode and loop through the place vector looking for a match but the repeated string comparisons take forever as I'd expected. I also experimented with hashing the text but I still couldn’t get it anywhere near as fast as PHP.

I think PHP is written in C so my question is how does C manage to create this string index name functionality for PHP?
I’m not looking for the actual code or anything, it just seems to me that there must be some fundamental technique that is used for this and I was just wondering if there is anyone out there who could briefly explain it.

Thanks in advance.
C

Comment: There's no such thing as an array with strings as the index.  You're looking for something that doesn't exist.  PHP just happens to use the same syntax for arrays as for maps.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for a description of how maps are usually implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought I could speed this up using C++ but of course C++ does not allow (as far as I know) arrays with a string as the index.

It does, You can use **[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)** as an Associative array.

Comment: std::unordered_map is better for strings

Comment: @Dani: Yes that is correct,but it comes as `std::tr1::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_map` i.e: comes under `tr1` or C++11.

Comment: _No._  This is not a good rumor to spread.  There's a big difference between arrays and maps; the fact that PHP uses the same syntax for both does not change this.

Comment: @Dani: It is just not everyone is not allowed to use them.In case allowed,Yes `std::unordered_map` is an better option than `std::map` in this case for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Berkeley DB. Back in the days it was the fastest but by default it's disk oriented. I don't know if you can run it in memory but you can always mount the directory from tmpfs.

PHP propably uses some external class for hashing table. You can get quite far by writing a quicksearch algorithm. Sort the keys and check up the key in the middle. Then again in middle until you've found the key. You can also use MD5() for keys as it's faster than pure string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ only allow integer types to be array indexes, and strings aren't even a type on C/C++, they're actually an array of chars.
As stated above, use `std::map` or similar.